# Use decorator to collect instance methods?

Tags: python

I have this class:

```
class Foo(object):

    handlers = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass
```

How could I implement decorator `@collect_handler`

```
 class Foo(object):

    handlers = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass    

    @collect_handler
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @collect_handler
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

so that:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.handlers # [foo, bar]
```

?

is this possible?

Comment: Do you want `handlers` to return bound or unbound instance methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo(object):
    handlers = []
    def collect_handler(handlers):
        def wrapper(func):
            handlers.append(func)
            return func
        return wrapper
    collect_handler = collect_handler(handlers)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass    

    @collect_handler
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @collect_handler
    def bar(self):
        pass


foo = Foo()
print(foo.handlers)
```

yields

```
[<function foo at 0xb770d994>, <function bar at 0xb770d9cc>]
```

These are not unbound methods; they are just plain functions. (There is no checking that the the first argument is an instance of `Foo`.) However, they should suffice. (Note in Python3 there are no more unbound methods; the distinction between unbound methods and plain functions was removed.)

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate way without using decorators.

```
f = Foo()
[m for m in dir(f) if getattr(f,m).__doc__ == "COLLECT"]
```

The above statement uses List comprehension in Python.
`dir` is a built-in function which would return all attributes of an object.
`getattr` is a built-in function to retrieve an attribute of an object.
`__doc__` is a python variable which holds the docstring for any python artifacts.

This should be your class definition:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass    

    def foo(self):
        "COLLECT"
        pass

    def bar(self):
        "COLLECT"
        pass
```